# Rolagem horizontal da DataGridViewer

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Bom dia, estou ajustando alguns datagrids do sistema, porém, um deles vai ter bastante colunas e o tamanho em relação a tela. Ou seja, ela precisa criar um scroll horizontal, mexi nos Property em scroll e outros e nenhum deles mudou. Tem alguma Property ou conjunto de Property que tem que mudar para que o scroll de rolagem horizontal apareça ou preciso alterar algo nas colunas?

Agradeço pela atenção!

Answer (score 0):

o Bootstrap tem uma classe CSS chamada `table-responsive`, utilizo ela nos Grid's para que eles rolem horizontalmente quando as colunas não cabem na tela, você pode tentar fazer assim:

```
<div class="table-responsive">

  <%-- DataGridViewer aqui --%>

</div>

<style>

  .table-responsive {
    min-height: .01%;
    overflow-x: auto;
  }

  .table-responsive {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
  }

</style>
```